# Apache2 set up multiple site with subdomain not working?

Tags: wordpress, apache, subdomain, lamp

I want to run 2 Wordpress sites on my VPS installed LAMP stack.

Site 1: `test1.example.com`
Site 2: `test2.example.com`

Here are my config files:

`test1.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test1.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/test1
    <Directory "/path/test1">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`test2.example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test2.example.com
    DocumentRoot /path/test2
    <Directory "/path/test2">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I did `a2ensite` for both configs files and restarted the apache2 service.

But the problem is the domain `test2.example.com` and `example.com` (not set up yet) automatic redirect to `test1.example.com`. It return code 301 when for the `test2` page (use `Inspect tool` in Chomre to see). I also check config for database of site2 and it's correct. When I `a2dissite` `test1.example.com.conf`, domain `test2.example.com` work fine.

Here is `.htaccess` file:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /reeme/
       RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /reeme/index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Whenever Apache cannot match the request to a VirtualHost, it uses the first one it read from configuration.  So if you always get test1.example.com, it means there is something preventing requests to other sites from matching VirtualHost definitions.  And if you remove test1, Apache only sees the VirtualHost for test2. 
 What version of Apache are you using?  What directory is the `.htaccess` located in?

Comment: I use Apache 2.4.29. The `.htacccess` file located in wordpress folder, both site are the same.